# How to connect 2 external non Apple monitors with 13" MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, 4k

This MacBook Pro has only two USB-C ports. Since one is used to charge the laptop (the monitor can't charge the laptop), there is only one available port to plug a monitor.

Is it possible to connect two external monitors, for example with a hub? If so, can we have 4K resolution for at least one monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get two external monitors on your 13" MacBook Pro, you need

- a [video adapter that supports pass-through charging](http://radnex.us/usbc-multi-port-adapter-power-delivery-hdmi)
- a [Type C DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K)

Both displays can support 4K at 60Hz.  From [Apple's technical specifications page](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/):

> #### Video Support
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
> - Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

Comment: This answer allows to connect one external monitor only. We still don't know when using a hub, if it impacts the maximum resolution (2 monitors into one USB-C channel).

Comment: @Kwadz.  Incorrect.  You have two ports.  One gets the hub with power pass through and the second port gets the cable.  To connect two monitors you need to use *both* ports.

Comment: Got it, so you mean we use one USB-C from the laptop to connect a first monitor and the HDMI of the hub to connect a second monitor. I imagined both monitors connected with Display port, that's why I didn't get you first time. Anyway by using the two ports of the MacBook the max resolution won't be affected. Thanks.